# Internal company data: policy and documentation

Tags: business, companies, industry

Does anyone know of any examples of companies that have published their internal documentation and policies, or a handbook. Things such as:

- Workflow
- Communication guidelines
- Corporate identity guidelines
- Tools

Comment: opensource.com continually writes about open.org. not 100% what you are asking for, but very informative in my opinion: https://opensource.com/open-organization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some more interesting ones:

**[The Ropes at Disney (1943)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZsWt_jNNHn2_dSODQlONDqsIzyJcSG38vYH2nBprwy4ElMM68yhhKX4fztew/view)**

Interestingly constructed with a rope going throughout the document; women at the time had 10 sick days and men only 5.

[image: Disney Lot Map]

**[Steam (2012)](http://media.steampowered.com/apps/valve/Valve_NewEmployeeHandbook.pdf)**

A fun read on the flat organization front and approach to employee development.

[image: When to communicate]

[The Motley Fool](http://thefoolrules.com/home)

Website designed for easy policy information dispersal.

[image: Communication Methods and Stack]

[Big Spaceship](http://www.bigspaceship.com/bsscom2013/wp-content/themes/bss/assets/pdf/BigSpaceship_OurManual_Digital.pdf)

A company with a portion dedicated into the handbook justifying having dogs in the office.

Answer (score 2):

I have found two tech companies that have published their handbook online:

#### [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/handbook/)

A remote-only company that's developing an alternative to github for IT development. The company is dedicated to being open and transparent, and by default all they make everything publically available (except for "financial information, legal, job applications/compensation/feedback and partnerships with other companies.")

You can find the source code of their handbook [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/www-gitlab-com).

#### [Clef](https://github.com/clef/handbook)

A cryptography company that creates an app that allows you to log into anything where Clef is installed without requiring a username or password.